# CakePHP wants to access an ACL node

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I've done a simple "change_email" function with its view and all the stuff in the controller. Everything is actually working fine except saving the data. When I submit my form and my model actually runs its save()-Method CakePHP throws an error:

> AclNode::node() - Couldn't find Aro node identified by "Array (
>   [Aro0.model] => User [Aro0.foreign_key] => 11 ) "

Of course he doesn't find the node, since it hasn't been created (when a user registers his account, a node won't be created automatically). I'm curious about why my model wants to find the node since its not needed for the actual operation.

```
public function change_email()
    {
        if ($this->request->is("put")) {
            if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
                $this->User->validator()
                    ->add('password', array(
                        'valid' => array(
                            'rule' => 'validatePassword'
                        )
                    ))
                    ->add('email_confirm', array(
                        'valid' => array(
                            'rule' => 'validateEmail'
                        )
                    ));
                if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                    $this->set("status", true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thats my code in the controller. The model has no real effect except its beforeFilter() method which only hashes the password.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Using Acl usually requires parnetNode() and bindNode() methods within your User and Group model if it applies.

[Using AclBehavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/acl.html#using-the-aclbehavior)

> Most of the AclBehavior works transparently on your Model’s
>   afterSave(). However, using it requires that your Model has a
>   parentNode() method defined. This is used by the AclBehavior to
>   determine parent->child relationships. A model’s parentNode() method
>   must return null or return a parent Model reference.

Within `User` model belonging to a `Group` model

```
public function parentNode() {
    if (!$this->id && empty($this->data)) {
        return null;
    }
    $data = $this->data;
    if (empty($this->data)) {
        $data = $this->read();
    }
    if (!$data['User']['group_id']) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return array('Group' => array('id' => $data['User']['group_id']));
    }
}

public function bindNode($user) {
    return array('model' => 'Group', 'foreign_key' => $user['User']['group_id']);
}
```

Within `Group` model, or if the `User` model doesn't have any parent associations, it should return null

```
public $actsAs = array('Acl' => array('type' => 'requester'));

public function parentNode() {
    return null;
}
```

You will also want to make sure you are updating your acos table with new methods and controllers.  [AclExtras](https://github.com/markstory/acl_extras/tree/2.0) is a nice plugin that can automate this for you.

Comment: I have defined parentNode() in my Model returning _null_.